# Stop a hover's 'out' event from triggering when hovering over another item overlaid over the first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a `video` element. I want some control buttons to appear when the user hovers over the video that allows them to pause/play and mute/unmute it. Here's my html, CSS and jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<video autoplay muted>
    <source src="<?=get_template_directory_uri()?>/video/bfvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <img src="<?php the_field('hero_image'); ?>" class="hero-text img-res" alt="<?php the_field('hero_image_alt_text'); ?>"/>
</video>
<div class="videoMute videoButton">M</div>
<div class="videoPause videoButton">P</div>
```

**js**

```
heroVideo.hover(        
        function() {
            // In
            console.log('In');
            $('.videoButton').fadeIn(100);
            //heroVideo.prop('muted','');
        },
        function () {
            // Out  
            console.log('Out');
            $('.videoButton').fadeOut(100);
            //heroVideo.prop('muted','true');
        }
    );
```

**CSS**

```
.videoButton {
    background: #ccff00;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    bottom:50px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:none;
}

.videoMute {
    left:50px;  
}

.videpPause {
    left:250px; 
}
```

The buttons appear and disappear as desired when I hover in and out of the video, but when I hover over the buttons, I'm technically hovering off the video, because I'm hovering on the buttons instead (though I'm still in the video's area on the screen). Therefore, the buttons disappear when I hover over them.

Is there any way of preventing this? I want the buttons to appear whenever I'm in the video's area, regardless of whether my cursor is *actually* on that element.

Comment: If you only need pause/play, mute/volume, fullscreen; you can enable the browser's default HTML5 player controls.

Comment: @pol - Sure, but they're a bit ugly. I was trying to get something more inline with the site's layout (ps. I know the current CSS is far from beautiful - this is just the test layout before I beautify it once I've for this problem solved).

Comment: if you wrap the video and the buttons within the same container div and use your hover events on the container, it will solve your problem much more easily.

Comment: @klikas - Ah, of course! If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @BFWebAdmin thanks, it's done :)

Comment: what is stopping you from replicating the `heroVideo.hover()` functions to a say something like `buttonVideo.hover` as well ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa - Nothing, but you still get the "out" part of the hover function from the video, so the buttons will still flicker in and out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap the video and the buttons within the same container `div` and use your hover events on the container, it will solve your problem much more easily.

Something like:

```
<div class="video-container">
   <!-- your video here -->
   <!-- your buttons here -->
</div>
```

Then add the hover event handlers to video-container.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **child selectors** after wrapping your entire video into one container.

How this works is:

If the video is directly inside the container:

```
#container:hover > #video { css }
```

If the video is next to (after containers closing tag) the container:

```
#container:hover + #video { css }
```

If the video is somewhere inside the container:

```
#container:hover #video { css }
```

Edit: To include how this would be reflected in your code.

```
<div id="container">

    <video autoplay muted>
        <source src="<?=get_template_directory_uri()?>/video/bfvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <img src="<?php the_field('hero_image'); ?>" class="hero-text img-res" alt="<?php the_field('hero_image_alt_text'); ?>"/>
    </video>

    <div class="videoMute videoButton">M</div>
    <div class="videoPause videoButton">P</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Doing it via CSS doesn't (directly) allow for the jQuery animations I have in my code.

Answer (score -1):

Put the buttons as child's from the `video`, or create a container and put both video and buttons in him, then put the hover event on the container instead.

This is happening because button `z-index` is greather than the `z-index` of `video` tag.

Comment: If the z-index of the buttons isn't greater than that of the videos, they won't show at all.

Comment: Correctly, I didn't tell you to decrease the z-index. The solution is in the first paragraph of the answer.

As the z-index is greater, when you hover it, you aren't hovering the video tag.